# Unsubscribe error message

Tags: drupal, civimail, email

If the Civi user isn’t logged into their account then they get the following error when clicking token inside their email footer:

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. >
>
> You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
>
> A fatal error was triggered: is not of type Text
>
> Return to home page.

The link being generated in the mailing is:

`https://example.org/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=15266&qid=6919138&h=e77ea82acfec8278`

**Is this expected behavior?**

Comment: Can you include an example of the link which is being placed in the footer? Replace the URL with "example.com", also replace any Contact ID or Checksum present in the URL (<CID> and <CHECKSUM> would work to replace where these are printed in the URL)

Comment: It’s just the url generated by the system with a checksum that shows as a hyperlink in the email. You want that whole string? It works and shows a confirm form only if I’m logged into the drupal account but if I click log out then go back to the email and click the hyperlink then I get a horrible error that is super unfriendly to the end user. I’d rather it just instructed them to log in before hand.

Comment: This is the url:  https://example.org/civicrm/mailing/optout?reset=1&jid=15266&qid=6919138&h=e77ea82acfec8278

Comment: Thanks @WebmasterTheCMG can you provide the CiviCRM and Drupal versions and confirm that anonymous users have the _CiviMail: access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages_ permission on the Admin -> People -> Permissions screen in Drupal?

Comment: Yes the flag is on and I did look there first. Drupal 7.59 and Civi 5.1.0 are version numbers. These are current releases.

Comment: Can you provide a backtrace of the error (you may need to go through the backtrace to redact any confidential information about your environment). https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/ I know it's probably frustrating that I'm not giving you solutions or answers - but need to understand what's going on first!

Comment: I do not have backtrace turned on in debugging. Not sure what that would do for you to help answer. Yes it seems that way. I would guess others have this happen too in their Civi mail

Comment: We've got 8 Civi 5.1.2 + Drupal 7.59 sites in production I've tried to reproduce this on 3 sites with no luck.

Comment: Then you are perfect one to answer it. Not sure what info you still need. We have a very vanilla install without tons of customizations or hand coding of any kind. Upgrades have been easy.

Comment: Ideally the backtrace if you can turn it on and reproduce the error - it'll point us perfectly to where the error is being triggered - I know it's a pain and I'm sorry for that for what it's worth!

Comment: Ok I will turn on. Then where is log located?

Comment: Assuming defaults - sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

Comment: Here is the error now :

Comment: Sorry - no error in that comment - pasting the error won't work - you'd need to use (e.g. pastebin or GitHub Gist)

Comment: I’m having trouble doing this on mobile

Comment: Oh - that's understandable - post it when you can and I'll keep tabs on the issue.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to figure out how to log into this forum from my computer and was using the app.  Of course nothing is easy.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wsyL3Ufn

Comment: Can you try disabling the CiviAlerts extension - this is known to cause problems for unauthenticated users (https://github.com/mr-vara/me.vara.civialerts/pull/1)

Comment: Nice support HT

Comment: How do I get the newest version of CiviAlerts? I am baffled by GIT and how this is supposed to work.  I have tried CLONE but that does not get these changes.  I have tried PULL and that does not work either. I am frustrated and do not know how to get this extension !

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out with the help of the back trace from the error.

It was the CiviAlerts extension which I had installed apparently, I really liked this CiviAlerts too because it let me give my mail admins a message window to see when I wanted all of them to do something differently (like use a different smart group for example in a mailing).

Anyway I just went in and turned off that Extension then redid my test and guess what?  The form showed up with the email (and a few asterisks) and a confirmation page.  Problem solved.  Thanks for the assistance.

The changes described in this Pull Request for the CiviAlerts extensions *should* resolve the issue: https://github.com/mr-vara/me.vara.civialerts/pull/1

Comment: No problem - if you implement the changes from this PR (https://github.com/mr-vara/me.vara.civialerts/pull/1) you can re-enable the CiviAlerts extension.

Comment: How do I implement these changes?  I am baffled how to do it,  I tried CLONE and that does not get the changes.  And I do not have a very good understanding of GIT